# Adding dll reference to visual studio c# project visible on github

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I added a reference to a local dll on my PC. 
How do I make sure that it will have a local reference so that when i upload to github, anyone who opens it have also access to the dll?

I tried to copy it under a folder in my project but I could not reference it there.

Comment: You simply don't do that. You can publish that dependency as NuGet...

Comment: Ok, but can I do it?

Comment: You can include whatever files you want if that the question you are asking.\

Comment: Ok, and can i reference to them? Using a local reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I could not reference it there"?

Answer (score 0):

You put your local dll inside the bin folder of your project and then reference it to your project and when you upload your project to GitHub it will automatically uploaded

Comment: I placed it under the bin 0 there are 2 more folders there: 
bin\Debug
bin\Release
mydll.dll

Now how do I add reference link to it?
If I add reference and browse to it it shows the link as full path to my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a folder in the solution level to store the shared libraries.

2.Copy the dll files into it.

3.In VS > Solution Explorer, right-click on solution > Add > New solution folder; Create a folder that has the same name in step 1.

4.Right-click on the folder we just created > Add > Exiting item; Select the dll files in step2.

5.Reference the dll files from the shared folder.

6.Make sure the dll files reference as a relative path in csproj file. For instance,

```
<Reference Include="NLog">
  <HintPath>..\Shared References\NLog.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Moreover, check if your gitignore setting excludes the dll files.

And still, Nuget is definitely a better option.

Comment: Create a folder with windows explorer or with VS?

Comment: @dandan with both, and add dll as existing item